# Full Text Search For Excel Files

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I have several 100 excel files that are not normalized enough for me to efficiently import into the tables of my database.  It is difficult to find information but from what I have seen it is possible to index xlsx files with FTS.  I am not really looking to implement an alternate database for this as it is a one time thing that will not receive new data.

Would it be possible to do this with FTS and if so could someone point me in the right direction as the info I've found on msdn is quite vague.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTS is a feature in SQL Server, The data you want to create FTS for needs to in a SQL Server database.

Excel being in Excel and not in SQL Server , you will not be able to create FTS for them Excel sheets.

But if you import that data into SQL Server only then you will be able to make use of FTS features, till then unfortunately FTS is not an option for you.

Comment: So the filters in this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142499.aspx are not for loading data from excel ?

Comment: This article talks about if you have documents stored in a SQL Server database (varbinary) you can have FTS enabled to search them documents.

Comment: So if I created a table and imported the documents as binary then I could use full text search on the contents ?

Comment: Yes, thats right according to the documentation. My personal experience is a bit different but documentation says so :)

Comment: I'm not super optimistic either given my experience with FTS.  Do you have another suggestion to accomplish this ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the only two options I can think of are 1) import data into sql server 2) import docs into sql server. :S

Answer (score 2):

I have done something similar using BULK. I would suggest taking a look at it

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-bulk-insert-to-load-a-text-file

How it works is excel data can be taken as a text file. Each column is separated by a ";" and each row by "\n" you can then use BULK to crawl through your excel sheet and insert it in a table.

Note that all the values coming from BULK are text values. So if your table contains int values, for example, you will need a temporary table.

CREATE TABLE #TEMPORARYTABLE(

)
The # creates a table that only exists until you disconnect from sql server.
All values in that table should be nvarchars

You can then insert into your real table the #TEMPORARYTABLE and CAST the Nvarchar values to int values or whatever else you need

Comment: The problem is that the excel files are hideously formated

Comment: I have edited my post explaining how, from the experience I have had with it, excel files could be crawled through. If the data in your excel files are all messed up I can't help much more @bumble_bee_tuna

Comment: The issue is that it is not a traditional X,Y grids there are multiple sheets with multiple sub grids non of which is normalized effectively